# How to stop postgresql to free the port 5432

Tags: 14.04, gnome, updates, postgresql

I am trying to run this command to install wsgi for python Flask:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

I am getting this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] yes
Setting up postgresql-common (190.pgdg14.04+1) ...
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.5 database server                                                                       * Error: Port conflict: another instance is already running on /var/run/postgresql with port 5432
                                                                                                         [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package postgresql-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of postgresql-9.5:
 postgresql-9.5 depends on postgresql-common (>= 158~); however:
  Package postgresql-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package postgresql-9.5 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of postgresql-contrib-9.5:
 postgresql-contrib-9.5 depends on postgresql-9.5 (= 9.5.12-1.pgdg14.04+1); however:
  Package postgresql-9.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package postgresql-contrib-9.5 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
 postgresql-common
 postgresql-9.5
 postgresql-contrib-9.5
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried many solutions to stop postgres such as:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql stop
```

2.

```
update-rc.d postresql off
```

3.

```
chconfig postresql off
```

4.

```
netstat -ntulp|grep 5432
```

5.

```
sudo service postgresql stop
```

All commands showing that I am being able to stop postgresql but when I run my command again to install wsgi, it gives me the same error again!!!

Comment: The problem is not that postgres owns a port, it's that the postgresql-9.5 package have been left in this state: _dependency problems - leaving unconfigured_ and at this point apt will refuse to install **anything** until it's fixed. Removing the postgresql-9.5 package will probably solve it.